# How to create type predicate to check for 2 types of setState in react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following state porps where i have 2 types for the passed down set state function from the parent component my issue is that i want to make a predicate that will set the current type.

```js
interface Props {
  name: 'a' | 'b';
  id: string;
  disabled: boolean;
  mainGroup: string;
  currentGroup: (a| b)[] | null;
  // The selected state
  selected: InitialAState | InitialBState;
  setSelected: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<InitialAState>> | 
  React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<InitialBState>>;
  
}
```

```js
const isSetSelectedA = (setSelected: any): setSelected is React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<InitialAState>>  => {
  return setSelected // check the function type ??? 
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't check the "function return type" in runtime, as types don't exist in runtime.

Have you considered [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#union-types)?

Assuming that `name` is the type discriminator:

```js
type Props = PropsA | PropsB;

interface PropsA {
  name: 'a';
  id: string;
  disabled: boolean;
  mainGroup: string;
  currentGroup: a[] | null;
  // The selected state
  selected: InitialAState;
  setSelected: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<InitialAState>>; 
}

interface PropsB {
  name: 'b';
  id: string;
  disabled: boolean;
  mainGroup: string;
  currentGroup: b[] | null;
  // The selected state
  selected: InitialBState;
  setSelected: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<InitialBState>>; 
}

if (props.name === 'a') {
    props.setSelected    // gets automatically casted
    ...
```

Or check the discriminator in your proposed function:

```js
const isSetSelectedA = (setSelected: unknown): setSelected is React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<InitialAState>> => {
  return props.name === 'a';
};
```